# what is readyshare?

Tags: macos

I noticed the `readyshare` shared device has popped up in my finder windows. What is `readyshare`?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Readyshare is a Netgear Product**

[**Readyshare**](http://www.netgear.com/readyshare?cid=gwmng) was created by [**Netgear**](http://www.netgear.com/?cid=gwmng) to share services through their various products.

One of it's purposes is to advertise storage from their line of routers and/or wifi access points.  It allows you to use a USB device in the router or other Netgear product to share it to other users within your private network.  Files can be written to and/or read from the device.

**Attributes of Readyshare**

- Network Storage
- Streaming multimedia files within your LAN
- File Sharing
- Print Sharing
- TCP port 20,005
- Shares over wireless and wired connections within the LAN